# Equation on cross product

Tags: cross-product

I have to solve the equation $\vec x\times\vec a=\vec b-\vec x$  ,   where $\vec x, \vec a,\vec b$ are vectors and the last two are known.

I have proven that $\vec a\cdot \vec x=\vec a\cdot\vec b$, but that is all.

Thank you in advance !

<< Symbol : $\vec a \vec b = \vec a \cdot \vec b$ >>

Comment: What do you mean by $\vec{a}\vec{x}$?

Comment: Probably dot product $\overrightarrow{a}\cdot\overrightarrow{x}$.

Comment: Please, how do you define the cross product ?

Comment: Cross product means vector product. In Greece we use also '' external product ''.

Answer (score 2):

Given:

$$\vec{x} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}, \vec{a} = \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{bmatrix} ~\text{and}~ \vec{b} = \begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{bmatrix},$$
the equation
$$\vec x\times\vec a=\vec b-\vec x$$

corresponds to:

$$\begin{cases}
a_3 x_2 - a_2 x_3 +x_1 - b_1 = 0\\
a_1 x_3 - a_3 x_1 +x_2 - b_2 = 0\\
a_2 x_1 - a_1 x_2 +x_3 - b_3 = 0
\end{cases}.$$

The solution is:

$$x_1 = \frac{a_1(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) + b_1 + a_2 b_3 - a_3 b_2}{|\vec{a}|^2 + 1},$$

$$x_2 = \frac{a_2(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) + b_2 + a_3 b_1 - a_1 b_3}{|\vec{a}|^2 + 1},$$

$$x_2 = \frac{a_3(\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}) + b_3 + a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}{|\vec{a}|^2 + 1}.$$

Note that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$ is the scalar product, while $|\vec{a}|^2 = \vec{a} \cdot \vec{a}$ is the squared norm of the vector $\vec{a}$.

Comment: So$$\vec{x}=\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}{a^2+1}.$$

Comment: @J.G. Yes! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $\vec{x}=\vec{y},\,\vec{x}=\vec{y}+\vec{z}$ both work, $\vec{z}\times\vec{a}=-\vec{z}$, so $\vec{z}$ is self-orthogonal and vanishes, and the solution $\vec{x}$ is unique. Now try the Ansatz $\vec{x}=A\vec{a}+B\vec{b}+C\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$. As I noted in a comment on @thecandyman's answer, you should find$$\vec{x}=\frac{(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b})\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{a}\times\vec{b}}{a^2+1}.$$

Comment: +1. I was wondering if one can also exploit the fact that $\vec{x} \times \vec{a}$ can be rewritten as $-S(\vec{a}) \vec{x}$, where $S(\vec{a})$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.